# Is it possible to filter by taxonomy field?

Tags: 7, views

Is it possible to filter by taxonomy field in a view, using Drupal 7?

I will try to explain the problem with a silly example: let's say I have a list of countries that are a taxonomy term and each country has a field "Language".

I also have a list of items each linked to a specific country.

I would like to be able to filter by language, getting only those items that have a country where e.g Spanish is spoken.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Absolutely. When creating a new View, be sure to show "Taxonomy Terms" rather than Content. Change "of type" to be Countries.

[image]

After that, you should be able to add a Filter for the language field.